# How to execute code in `if __name__ == "__main__"` from another python file

Tags: python, namespaces, pytest, program-entry-point

In my python file I have a function that takes some parameters and in the same file I have an `if __name__ == "__main__"` clause that runs this function with a particular set of parameters (for a user to showcase what it does). Like so,

```
def foo(arg1, arg2):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    arg1 = 1
    arg2 = 2
    foo(arg1, arg2)
```

Furthermore, I also have another file with tests which is used by pytest. I'd like to have one of the test run exactly what is written inside the above mentioned if clause, i.e. execute

```
arg1 = 1
arg2 = 2
foo(arg1, arg2)
```

Is this possible without copying the code to the file containing the tests?

Comment: The whole point of that block is for code that cannot be accessed from another file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, im no expert at that but how about redicrecting your `if __name__ == "__main__":`
to another function and call that function from your other file?

file1:

```
def main_file1:
  arg1 = 1
  arg2 = 2
  foo(arg1, arg2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main_file1()
```

---

file2:

```
from file1 import *

def somefunc():
  main_file1()
```

However, im not sure why you would want to do that anyways. Usually you only have 1 main function in your whole project to get things rolling and call other functions from there.

And ultimately this kind of fails the purpose of a main function of a file

Comment: This does what I want. Responding to your comment: Maybe my meaning of a main function is off, but the entire point of the my code is to implement some mathematical functionality in `foo` and what gets called inside the `if __name__ == "__main__"` block is just there to showcase functionality.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the files

## file1.py

```
def foo(arg1, arg2):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    arg1 = 1
    arg2 = 2
    foo(arg1, arg2)
```

and `file2.py` is in the same directory you can:

## file2.py

```
from file1 import foo
arg1 = 1
arg2 = 2
foo(arg1, arg2)
```

You will need to redefine `arg1` and `arg2` like you have, but then its just a matter of importing the function you'd like. This will give you the function, but none of the global variables of `file1.py` because these are protected by the `if __name__ == "__main__"` statement

**UPDATE**

If you don't want to have to reassign within `file2.py` you can do something like this:

## file1.py

```
def foo(arg1, arg2):
    pass

def new_function(): #make a new function that you can import
    arg1 = 1
    arg2 = 2
    foo(arg1, arg2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    new_function()
```

## file2.py

```
from file1 import new_function
new_function()
```

This is not the worst because you are still containing `arg1` and `arg2` as local variables so there is not a huge namespace concern, but now you can import them because they are not protected within the `if name == main` section of your code.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I would like to avoid having to copy the parameter assignment.

Comment: There is no way around this because they are protected within `if name == main`. You would have to take them out of that block to be able to access them. The **entire** purpose of `if name == main` blocks is to prevent namespace collusion by preventing separate files/scripts from accessing that section of code. I'll post an update on what you might want to do